# how to make angularjs html expire when html changes

Tags: angularjs

How can I remove user's html file cache when our online website's html changes. we use angularjs and the template is html

```
.when('/search/:key',{
    templateUrl:'resources/views/route/search.html',
```

Comment: You can use ServiceWorker to manage the cache.